Using private npm registry with CodeQL autobuild
We've started using private npm packages in one of our repository's which we authenticate to using a npmrc file.
However we are now having problems with our Github Action CodeQL step failing due to it not being authenticated.
I've tried adding an additional step to our CodeQL Yaml setup before the autobuild step but it still fails when trying to execute npm install during the autobuild.
Is there any way to fix this without switching from autobuild -> manual?
This is the step I've added before the Autobuild.
...
- name: Authenticate with GitHub Packages
    run: |
      echo "@private-repository:registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com" >> .npmrc
      echo "//npm.pkg.github.com/:_authToken=${{ secrets.NPM_TOKEN_HERE }}" >> .npmrc
      echo "//npm.pkg.github.com/:always-auth=true" >> .npmrc

- name: Autobuild
    uses: github/codeql-action/autobuild@v3
...


Have you attempted using setup-node? https://github.com/actions/setup-node/blob/main/docs/advanced-usage.md#use-private-packages .  Configuring the environment prior to the analyze step should in theory work as you show.  I believe npm via Autobuild.sh only is used to pull down tsc when typescript is detected.
